# Android Widget Icon Size Layout

Tags: android, layout, widget

Wanted nice Android Image Icon for Widget on Home screen.

Problem Widget is too big.  I adjusted the dp to 32 x 32 but still height is too much.

Using Linear Layout thats all.  ImageButton inside the widget layout.  I get a nice frame, but the widget size is too big compared to the others, and too big compared to the icon I am using. So how to set max height or actual height of the widget is my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use "android:maxWidth" & "android:maxHeight" attributes in the appwidget_provider.xml to limit the size of the widget.